# Using "her/him" twice in a sentence

Tags: academic-writing, editing, word-choice, language, grammar

I'm an English learner, and I had a question about writing "her" twice in one sentence. For example, what would sound better for formal writing? (This is not an actual sentence that I'm using.)

1. *This part of the book highlights her kindness and confidence in herself.*

***or***

2. *This part of the book highlights her kindness and her confidence in herself.*

Answer (score 8):

Both works, but the first one is more consise so it is better.

The general rule of thumb when using pronouns multiple times in a phrase is that the pronoun should refer to the same noun.

That being said, there is an even better sentence: "This part of the book highlights her kindness and self-confidence."

I hope this helps, please comment if you need further assistance, I would be glad to help.